# wordpress category to a select box in meta box

Tags: wordpress

I need to list wordpress categories to a select (drop) box in backend. But the problem is, the select box is created by meta box plugin.

I got this code but I can't able to use it in backend meta box.

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
```

Comment: http://themeforest.net/forums/thread/list-of-custom-post-type-categories-inside-wp-metabox/51844. read this link

Comment: Thanks for the link. :) Finally I solved it.